# windows 8 resolution bug

Tags: windows, windows-8, resolution

I have a problem with windows 8 resolution. It is set to 1920x1080 but it displays less! the image shows the actual size I get in firefox. (the height is the available one, full height-firefox menus). My problem is the width that is less then 1920 and the problem is not just with firefox, chrome and ie shows the same, everything on desktop is too big and even games don't show up as they should. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2):

You have an increased DPI value which reduces the usable size on the screen but makes the text easier to read. You can set the DPI value back to 100% to use all space.

Comment: Yes, that’s probably it. wenthus, notice that 1920/1536=125% which is a common scaling factor.